# Use wifii instead of Ethernet for certain address (win10)

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, firewall

I wonder if is possible to use wifii only for specific address, maybe configured on some file.
As I'm often behind a firewall, my need is to bypass this check by switching under an alternative network , through a mobile hotspot for example.
Is it possible by your knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the **route** command.

For example:

```
route -p ADD 151.101.1.69 192.168.35.254 METRIC 1
```

Where:

- **route** is the comand name
- **-p** is attribute which will make it persistent throughout reboots
- **ADD** is attribute for route creation
- **151.101.1.69** is your target IP
- **192.168.35.254** is Default Gateway of your WiFi adapter
- **METRIC** is something like priority, lower is greater

Comment: It works like a charm thank you very much